# Optimizing For Loop result?

Tags: c#, for-loop, optimization

I'm currently using this code to check if the DataReader has column existing:

```
public static class DataRecordExtensions
{
    public static bool HasColumn(this IDataRecord dr, string columnName)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            if (dr.GetName(i).Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I reuse this code alot and so it continuously runs through the For loop.

Is there anyway I can optimize this? For example, if a column is not existing, then it means result is same for everything and I don't have to iterate through everything again. Same with if it is existing, I know that it is existing and no need to go through the loop again.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you call this method for each record? A snippet of the code that uses this method would be helpful.

Comment: How about filling a `HashSet<string> existingColumnNames` *once* and then just check `existingColumnNames.Contains(columnName)`?

Comment: Thanks Ufuk and Corak. I like Corak's suggestion, I'll try to do this and see how the performance is.

Answer (score 3):

The code for the function is fine. You should check your calling code to not call this for every iteration of your DataReader or DataTable for example.

You should call this method *once* before iterating over all your records. Chances are slim that a table or cursor will not have the same columns for each row.

Comment: Good point, but does depend how many "clients" are calling this code, how they call it and how often.

Comment: Thanks nvoigt. As Matt has mentioned, we have several DB tables and a separate DataReader for each table. For each row of that table, we populate a collection of items. This part is where we call HasColumn because we can't populate an Item property if there is no column for that property in the DB.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem would be in the *calling* code... but you can avoid calling the method more than once in total, by changing your method to create and return a `HashSet<string>`:

```
public static class DataRecordExtensions
{
    public static ISet<string> GetFieldNames(this IDataRecord dr, StringComparer comparer)
    {
        var sequence = Enumerable.Range(0, dr.FieldCount)
                                 .Select(i => dr.GetName(i));
        return new HashSet<string>(sequence, comparer);
    }
}
```

You can then call that method with your first record, passing in `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` as the comparer, and you'll get back an `ISet<string>` that you can cheaply test for whether it contains a particular field name.

The awkward part is potentially calling this just once. You might need something like:

```
ISet<string> fields = null;
while (reader.Read())
{
    var record = ...;
    if (fields == null)
    {
        fields = record.GetFieldNames(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
    // Use fields and record here
}
```

You might also want to consider returning a `Dictionary<string, int>` instead of an `ISet<string>`, if you need the field *number* as well.

Comment: Thanks Jon! Very helpful and I think this is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to store your column names in a dictionary, you can then use this to look up the column name very quickly.

Given that you're using an extension method you'll need to use [ConditionalWeakTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx) to store and retrieve your dictionary for a given data reader. Check if it exists first, if not cache and store it using this approach.

Bear in mind the first time you call this it would probably be slower than it is now as you can't short circuit the method (as you need to get all the column names to cache). If this is an issue you could use a hybrid approach of caching up to the point you find the column you're after then exiting, next time if you don't find the column in your cache, keep searching and adding to the cache any new columns, again exiting as soon as you find the column you're after (or you get to the end of the columns).

I should say that which of these three approaches is best (your current plus these two) depends greatly on:

1. How many times you call this method for a given data reader
2. How many columns you have in your data reader, and
3. Which columns you search for and in which order

For example, if you had 100 columns in your reader and searched for columns at positions 97, then 98 then 99, my first approach above would probably be best (cache all on first use). If however you searched for columns at position 1 and then 100 and then a few in between the hybrid approach may be better. Searching a data reader just once anywhere you'd be better off with your current approach!

Comment: Thanks Matt! Will consider this!